# Passing a variable and query to Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is it possible to pass both an SQL query, e.g. `(<![CDATA[$P!{SQL}]]>)`, and a variable $V as parameters to a Jasper report at the same time?

Also, how can I pass the variable $V to my Jasper report using Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable is something that varies during the report generation, like the number of pages for example. So a variable (`$V`) is not something you can pass to a report. You may pass any value from your Java code to the report as a parameter (`$P`), though.

Answer (score 1):

Often it is desired to just transform some parameter in order to use it in a query (in this case, the following works :) ).

***E.g. (pseudo code - Groovy syntax!)***

parameter:

```
filtParamUserName = "foo"
```

"variable" (technically not: in this case ***another parameter following it***)<sup>1</sup>:

```
sqlCondUserName = $P{filtParamUserName} ? " and user_name = '$P{filtParamUserName}'" : ""
```

thus you could easily use it in your query like:

```
select * from bar where 1=1 $P{sqlCondUserName}
```

<sup>1</sup>: you have to set the `Default Value Expression` of the `sqlCondUserName` and `Is For Prompting = false`